# GlassFish Directory Disclosure Vulnerability

Tags: security, directory, glassfish

I have a Glassfish 4.1.1 server, there a vulnerability scan with MCafee Vulnerability Manager find that the server have Apache Tomcat Directory Disclosure Vulnerability [FID 10109] on admin server (port 4848) I search and only find solutions for Directory Transversal vulnerability, any one have solved this vulnerability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this is not actually a problem with GlassFish 4.1.1. It's very hard to find details on this without a CVE number, but I found a [McAfee PDF which lists the vulnerability](https://www.mcafee.com/us/resources/release-notes/foundstone/fsl_03_06_2012.pdf):

[image: McAfee bug details]

Searching for the BID number lead me to [a SecurityFocus page](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/5838/info) which lists the vulnerability as affecting Apache Tomcat 3.2, 15 years ago. So this bug is older than GlassFish itself.

Part of GlassFish is derived from Tomcat (portions of Catalina code), though it has changed a lot since then. The Tomcat code that does exist in GlassFish is not as old as this vulnerability so I don't think this is a problem here.

I don't know how the McAfee scan works, so it's hard to say whether it may have found something else and erroneously flagged it as this bug. Even then, I think McAfee is probably flagging things up wrongly, since the PDF I linked to earlier came from 10 years after the bug was actually found.

If you are concerned about security in GlassFish, though, I would recommend you look at Payara Server (**disclaimer**: I am an employee of Payara). There are a number of vulnerabilities in GlassFish which are now fixed in Payara Server, [detailed in the documentation](https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/content/security/security-fix-list.html).

More details on the way security vulnerabilities are addressed can be found in this ServerFault answer:
https://serverfault.com/a/818798/175741